# Android epub libraries

Tags: android, dropbox-api, epub

I am doing an application that uses DropBox API to list all the files which are epub compliant(in Dropbox). Then  it must show only the first page of the file(title), when you click the epub file, in a android ListView.

Should I download the whole epub file and then show the information, or is there a way to remotely open the file in  Dropbox(I looked  at possible methods in the API and found none),extract the title page, and then serve it to the phone by downloading it?

Comment: Please Check the answer below. If it has helped you solving the problem, then please do accept it. Thank You.

Comment: Note that there is no notion of "page" in an EPUB. At most, you can speak about "the first XHTML element listed in the <spine> of the OPF manifest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks the `ePub` file in a `Android ListView`, you should show a `ProgressBar` to the user and download that `ePub` file. After the download gets completed, you can then proceed the user to either a self implemented `ePub Viewer` within your App Or navigate the user to the suitable `Applications` already installed on the device for reading that `ePub` book.

1. In App ePub Viewer: 
   Here is a nice Tutorial which you can follow to implement it: 
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/592909/EPUB-Viewer-for-Android-with-Text-to-Speech
2. Launching External Apps for opening that ePub Ebook: 
   [open an epub file from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216203/open-an-epub-file-from-android-app)

P.S: If you are downloading the ePub file within your App's File Directory then you would have to make a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for your App, in order to grant access to the specific File within the Files Directory to be accessed by other Apps.

I hope this helps.